# No se realiza mi consulta SQL en una BD de Access por culpa de un acento

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

Estoy usando ODBC para hacer consultas en una Base de Datos de Access junto con php el problema es: Tengo un campo en la BD con acento en este caso la columna se llama **contactode** en ella tengo la opción **PISO**, **TELEFÓNICO** y **SERVICIO** cuando realizo mi consulta con PISO Y SERVICIO no hay ningún problema pero cuando quiero preguntar por **TELEFÓNICO** no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?(tanto en el código como en la BD están exactamente iguales con el acento)(tengo Office 2016 si influye en algo).

```
 <?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 # connect to a DSN "mydb" with a user and password 
 $connect4 = odbc_connect("proyecto", "usuario", "contra") or die("Error 
 Connect to Database");
 $query4 = "SELECT sum (IIF([contactode] = 'TELEFÓNICO',1,0))                 
            FROM datos 
            WEHRE datos.fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and 
                datos.fecha_reg  <= #$newDate2# and 
                vendedor <> 'CASA' 
            GROUP BY vendedor
            ORDER BY vendedor";
 # perform the query4
 $result4 = odbc_exec($connect4, $query4);
 # fetch the data from the database
 while(odbc_fetch_row($result4)){
     $d1 = round ($d1 = odbc_result($result4, 1));  
     $sumatoria += $d1;  
     print("<tr><td>$d1</td></tr>");    
 }
 print("<td> $sumatoria</td>");
 # close the connection
 odbc_close($connect4);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Si no usas el acento en la O para tu consulta, te devuelve algo!?.

Comment: debería de recibir números pero me da solo ceros

Comment: Hice un Select * From en esa columna y me da TELEF?NICO alguna idea?

Comment: Quizás no aporte como una respuesta directa a tu problema, ya que no domino PHP, pero encontré este apartado en [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311687/unable-to-retrieve-utf-8-accented-characters-from-access-via-pdo-odbc), en el cual hay una explicación completa sobre que debes hacer en tu código PHP, ya que lo que debes especificar es el UTF-8. Espero haber aportado en algo a la solución a tu problema. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que codificar lo que te devuelve tu consulta, en tu pregunta no veo claro donde traes el campo en cuestión, pero debería de ser algo así:

```
$texto_codificado = utf8_encode($row['campotelefonico']);
```

Comment: No me funcionó :(

Comment: Te recomiendo imprimir la consulta que se genera en PHP y probarla en tu manejador a ver si te funciona.

Comment: hice la consulta y me regresa TELEF?NICO, será algún problema con la base de datos?

Comment: Por eso no te regresa nada, entonces en tu base de datos no permite acentos por eso te coloca un carácter que no corresponde.

Comment: En la base de datos si está como TELEFÓNICO con acento, como le hago para que si los permita?

Comment: Ya no entendí en la Base de Datos al hacer el select ¿Si te aparecen los registros con acento?

Comment: La base de datos si tiene acentos pero cuando los imprimo en php me aparecen con ?. Ejemplo: en la base de datos sí está TELEFÓNICO pero cuando imprimo en php en chrome sale TELEF?NICO.

Comment: Lo que comentó Rostan arriba, parece ser que es la solución al problema que tengo pero no le entiendo como podría yo implementarlo en mi código

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, tendrias que aplicar el utf8_encode() al campo resultado de tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que me ayudaron pero ya resolví el problema, convirtiendo la palabra TELEFÓNICO a "UTF-8" "Windows-1254" porque con utf8_encode() no me funcionaba así quedó:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
# connect to a DSN "mydb" with a user and password 
$valor = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1254",'TELEFÓNICO');
$connect4 = odbc_connect("proyecto", "usuario", "contra") or die("Error 
Connect to Database");
$query4 = "SELECT sum (IIF([contactode] = '$valor',1,0))                 
 FROM datos where datos.fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and datos.fecha_reg  <= 
#$newDate2# and vendedor <> 'CASA' 
 GROUP BY vendedor
 ORDER BY vendedor";
 # perform the query3
$result4 = odbc_exec($connect4, $query4);
# fetch the data from the database
while(odbc_fetch_row($result4)){
 $d1 = round ($d1 = odbc_result($result4, 1));  
  $sumatoria += $d1;  
  print("<tr><td>$d1</td></tr>");   
}
print("<td> $sumatoria</td>");
# close the connection

odbc_close($connect4);
}
?>
```

Una disculpa por la mala identación.